# WordPress login form: rename label submit field

Tags: wordpress, authentication, label

I have created login form for a shortcode. I could rename the label for the username and the submit field. But I would also like to rename the submit field. Any suggestions?
Php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_shortcodes' );
function my_add_shortcodes() {
    add_shortcode( 'my-login-form', 'my_login_form_shortcode' );
}

function my_login_form_shortcode( $attr ) {
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
    return 'you0re already logged in';
$defaults = array(
    'label_username' => 'num dutilisader',
    'label_password' => 'plaid clav'
);
$attr = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $attr );
$attr['echo'] = false;
return wp_login_form( $attr );
}
```

Shortcode:

```
[my-login-form label_username="num d'utilisader" label_password="plaid clav" label_submit="s'annunziar"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the attribute `label_log_in` for the submit text

you can see the available parameters in the following code

`function wpfa_login_form( $args ) {

```
$defaults = shortcode_atts( array(
    'echo'              => false,
    'redirect'          => site_url( '/wp-admin/' ),
    'form_id'           => 'loginform',
    'label_username'    => __( 'Username', 'wpfa-textdomain' ),
    'label_password'    => __( 'Password', 'wpfa-textdomain' ),
    'label_remember'    => __( 'Remember Me', 'wpfa-textdomain' ),
    'label_log_in'      => __( 'Log In', 'wpfa-textdomain' ),
    'id_username'       => 'user_login',
    'id_password'       => 'user_pass',
    'id_remember'       => 'rememberme',
    'id_submit'         => 'wp-submit',
    'remember'          => true,
    'value_username'    => NULL,
    'value_remember'    => false
), $args, 'wpfa_login' );

$login_args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

return wp_login_form( $login_args );
```

} add_shortcode( 'wpfa_login', 'wpfa_login_form' );`

Here you can create a shortcode: `[wpfa_login label_log_in="Show Me The Way"]`.

You can try altering your code based on this